# Why is iam:PassRole required in this project?

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

I cloned this solution [azure-devops-on-aws](https://github.com/cloudopian/azure-devops-on-aws) and used `dotnet lambda deploy-serverless ...` to deploy the [MyLizardApp](https://github.com/cloudopian/azure-devops-on-aws/tree/master/MyLizardApp) to my personal AWS account.

During the learning curve, I created an S3 bucket `my-lizard-test`, IAM user group `MyLizardGroup` with user `lizard-user` and group policy `MyLizardApp-Policy`. Included in the policy are these services:

1. API Gateway (full access, all resources)
2. CloudFormation (full access, all resources)
3. Lambda (full access, all resources)
4. S3 (full access, all resources)

(Eventually) the deployment succeeded and I had a Lambda application serving the simple razor page showing the time.

I then copied the [LambdaEntryPoint.cs](https://github.com/cloudopian/azure-devops-on-aws/blob/master/MyLizardApp/LambdaEntryPoint.cs), [aws-lambda-tools-defaults.json](https://github.com/cloudopian/azure-devops-on-aws/blob/master/MyLizardApp/aws-lambda-tools-defaults.json) and [serverless.template](https://github.com/cloudopian/azure-devops-on-aws/blob/master/MyLizardApp/serverless.template) files to my own `dotnet core webapp` (also a razor project) and attempted to deploy it to the same AWS account with the same command. The only changes made were the namespace of the `LambdaEntryPoint` class (reflected in the `serverless.template` file) and the `.csproj` file to include:

```
<AWSProjectType>Lambda</AWSProjectType>
```

and:

```
<PackageReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer" Version="5.0.0" />
```

The `dotnet lambda deploy-serverless ...` command failed with the message:

```
User: arn:aws:iam::123456789120:user/lizard-user is not authorized to perform: iam:PassRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::123456789120:role/MyLizardAppServiceRole (Service: AWSLambdaInternal; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: 12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012; Proxy: null)
```

I got the command to succeed by adding the `IAM` service to the `MyLizardApp-Policy` with the `PassRole` (all resources).

Why was this necessary for my personal app and not the demo solution from github? If the answer is not clear, what should I be looking for as differences? My personal app is not significantly different from the demo solution and I don't think the functional differences (in C#) would matter.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever an AWS Service assumes (uses) an IAM Role, the service must have `iam:PassRole` permission to grant permission to use the Role. This required to prevent users from gaining too much permission.

For example, imagine a normal (non-Admin) user who launches an Amazon EC2 instance. When launching the instance, they can nominate an IAM Role to be assigned to the instance. If this user was permitted to select *any* IAM Role, they could select an Admin role and assign it to the EC2 instance. They could then login to the instance and use the credentials to make API calls as an Admin. This is an unwanted "privilege escalation".

Similarly, when an AWS Lambda function executes, it uses an IAM Role to obtain permissions. The `iam:PassRole` permission is used to control which roles a user can assign to the Lambda function.

So, there is something in that project that is trying to use an IAM Role and needs appropriate permissions.

Comment: But the files involved with deploying the lambda to AWS are the same in both projects. I'm looking for what is different, when I have changed only the namespace of the LambdaEntryPoint class.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we need to know what PassRole is:

> iam:PassRole is the permission that controls which users can delegate an IAM role to an AWS resource.

As I can see in the repo, there is a file for CodeDeploy which already have credentials so maybe you are using CodeDeploy.

But btw, you are using an instances to deploy a Lambda function, and you need to pass the role to that Lambda so that is what PassRole do

Answer (score 0):

AWS Services **cannot** directly assume service-linked roles. The role must be passed to the service by a user with the `iam::PassRole` permission.

The role-passing needs to be done **only once**, when a resource (e.g. EC2 instance) is created. After that the resource can assume the role repeatedly.

EC2 Instance profile is implemented this way. When a user launches an instance, it passes a role to the instance to act as an instance profile (it in addition needs `iam:AddRoleToInstanceProfile` for this case).

Other service-linked roles are also passed in this way.

Do not confuse it with the `iam::CreateRole` permission. A user may freely create service-linked roles, but is unable to pass the role to a service when needed.

In the management console, and to some extent in the CLI commands, role-passing is implicit, so you may encounter it without clear error messages when using non-root accounts.

As for why sometimes you need this permission, ands sometimes you don't, that is because when you use the root user, it will have `AdministratorAccess` which basically allows all actions on all resources.

If you create a new IAM user or account with blank permissions then you will need to add this permission manually.